# Building complex WHERE queries in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been having troubles with this for a while, and I can not figure it out (even I know it might be straightforward). I am taking my first steps in Laravel, and I want to build a query like this using Eloquent.

```sql
// This should be condition one
WHERE status NOT IN (4,99)
```

OR

```sql
// condition two
status NOT IN (4,99) AND ('column1' LIKE %XXXX% OR 'column2' LIKE %XXXX%)
```

I am doing this:

```php
$q->whereNotIn('order_stage_id', [99, 4])
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->whereNotIn('order_stage_id', [99, 4])
        ->orWhere('reference_number', 'like', '%'.$request->key.'%')
        ->orWhere('seller_remark', 'like', '%'.$request->key.'%')
        ->orWhere('companies.name', 'like', '%'.$request->key.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.name', 'like', '%'.$request->key.'%');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your eloquent code, your current query would look something like this:

`WHERE order_stage_id NOT IN (4,99) OR ( WHERE order_stage_id NOT IN (4,99) OR reference_number LIKE %XXXX% OR ...)`

You need to use a `where()` method to get the SQL `AND` operator, then use a closure to nest the `orWhere()` methods.

```
$q->whereNotIn('order_stage_id',[99,4])
    ->orWhere(function($query) {

    $query->whereNotIn('order_stage_id',[99,4])
        ->where(function($query) {

        $query->where('column_1', 'like', '%XXX%')
            ->orWhere('column_2', 'like', '%XXX%')
            ->orWhere('column_2', 'like', '%XXX%');
    });
});
```

Don't forget you will need to pass the `$request` object to each closure to be able to access it:

`->where(function($query) use ($request) {`